# how to get connect to wi-fi available in the listview

Tags: android, listview, wifimanager, wifi

i want to let the user to connect to the wi-fi which are available in the list of wi-fi.
i want to show a dialog alert which ask for password on tap of wi-fi if its protected and other settings just same as android  phone shows when we switch on wi-fi and tap on the available wi-fi.

What i have done so far is that i am getting a list of available wi-fi into the listview.

here's my code.

```
import java.util.List;

import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       WifiManager mainWifiObj;
       WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
       ListView list;
       String wifis[];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
          mainWifiObj.startScan();

    }
       protected void onPause() {
              unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
              super.onPause();
           }

       protected void onResume() {
              registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
              WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
              super.onResume();
           }
       class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
              @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
              public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                 List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
                 wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
                 for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                    wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
                 }
                 String filtered[] = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
                    int counter = 0;
                    for (String eachWifi : wifis) {
                        String[] temp = eachWifi.split(",");

                        filtered[counter] = temp[0].substring(5).trim()+"\n" + temp[2].substring(12).trim()+"\n" +temp[3].substring(6).trim();//0->SSID, 2->Key Management 3-> Strength


                        counter++;

                    }
                    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filtered));


              }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my code for WiFi Connection, just take a look at it, hope it helps:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        private WifiManager wifi;
        private ListView lv;
        // TextView textStatus;
        private Button buttonScan;
        private int size = 0;
        private List<ScanResult> results;
        private final Context context = this;
        private EditText pass;
        private String checkPassword = null;

        private String ITEM_KEY = "key";
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        private SimpleAdapter adapter;
    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                connectToWifi(arg2);
            }

        });

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showWifiSettings(arg2);
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist,
                R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY },
                new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                results = wifi.getScanResults();
                size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        arraylist.clear();
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) {
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put(ITEM_KEY,
                        results.get(size).SSID.toString()
                                + results.get(size).capabilities.toString());

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void showWifiSettings(int arg2) {
        showDialogOfOptions(arg2);
    }

    private void showDialogOfOptions(int arg2) {
        // Create a custom Dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Network details");
        TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID);
        TextView textBSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textBSSID);
        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        textSSID.setText(results.get(arg2).SSID);
        textBSSID.setText(results.get(arg2).BSSID);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void finallyConnect(String checkPassword, int position) {
        String networkSSID = results.get(position).SSID;
        String networkPass = checkPassword;

        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);

        // remember id
        int netId = wifi.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        wifi.disconnect();
        wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        wifi.reconnect();

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"";
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        wifi.addNetwork(conf);
    }

    private void connectToWifi(final int position) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connect);
        dialog.setTitle("Connect to Network");
        TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID1);
        TextView textBSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textBSSID1);
        TextView capabilities = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.textCapabilities);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        pass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
        textSSID.setText(results.get(position).SSID);
        textBSSID.setText(results.get(position).BSSID);
        capabilities.setText(results.get(position).capabilities);
        //
        // if button is clicked, connect to the network;
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkPassword = pass.getText().toString();
                finallyConnect(checkPassword, position);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your xml file please

Comment: dude just go through the code... if i give you the xml then it all spoon-feeding. take a look at `connectToWifi()` and `finallyConnect()` method, add the dialog code snippet to accept the password in `connectToWifi` , and then call `finallyConnect` with password and list view position

Comment: Is this code working for you perfectly...will work for the wi-fi which doesn't protected with the password?

Comment: it takes the password from a editText, in your case _i want to show a dialog alert which ask for password on tap of wi-fi if its protected_ you will show a dialog to ask the user for the password. and then call `finallyConnect` with the password as a parameter

Comment: and what if i want to connect to the wi-fi which is not protected with password who will i get  connect to them?

Comment: if you know that AP is not password protected, you can put a logic to bypass the "Password Input Dialog", and in `finallyConnect` bypass `wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);`

Comment: Will you please elaborate & what if i don't know that AP is password protected or not. Please tell me a solution to get connect to the AP's which are password protected and which are not password protected. Please help m searching it from last two days.

Comment: I have merged your code with mine  code and its juz showing a blank screen on Phone. Please help sir.